# Работа с базами данных в Spring

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, spring-data, spring-cloud

У меня есть проект java spring. Теперь мне нужно  добавить туда возможность работать с базами данных. Уча JPA я понял, что база данных использует отдельный порт, то есть её тоже нужно, так сказать, хостить. Но хостинг одновременно и сайта и базы данных как по мне слишком не удобно и мощьностезатратно. Кажется, что они будут мешать друг другу. Или что для нее нужен будет второй домен. Если что-то я думаю не так - поправьте меня.

Наверное идея тупая, но все же есть идея взять и создать свой (java)обработчик файла базы данных (формата json хотябы). И хранить файл в папке ресурсов что-ли.

Вообще идея жизнеспособная (и вообще будет ли spring видеть этот файл)? В правильном ли направлении я двигаюсь (Или я уже в дебри залез?)?

Comment: не в правильном. Даже если вы не предполагаете вообще "никакой" объем данных - лучше не городить велосипеды, а использовать in-memory database.

Comment: Как верно сказал kami - не нужно городить велосипеды. В качестве простенького варианта можно использовать sqlite, пример интеграции здесь - https://github.com/Semo/spring-jpa-sqlite-sample

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko и тогда я так понимаю, что хостить такую базу данных не нужно будет, в отличии от mysql? Если так, то можете добавить ответ, а я отмечу как правильный